# How to choose builders readthedocs is running?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm trying to install [Readthedocs](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org) on localhost, and everything is fine except it is running a lot of Sphinx builders I don't need. Specifically, it runs `python /path/to/sphinx-build -b latex` which ends up with error anyway because I don't have texlive installed.

How to make RTD to run just html builder for a repo?